# Get rows based on different column in single query using Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Let's say I have a table that looks like this:

```
name | link
-----------
 A   | asdf 
 A   | zxcv
 B   | qwer
 B   | rtyu
 C   | fghj
```

I am currently getting the results using 2 queries like the following using the $link variable:

```
// first query to get the row so I have the name
$m = Model::where('link', '=', $link)->get();    

// using the name, I get the rows I need
$results = Model::where('name', '=', $m->name)->get();
```

How can I do this in a single query?

Comment: what's the use case you have? Is the `$link` submitted from a form or something?

Comment: $link is a partial url

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Builder::whereIn`](https://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_whereIn) and subqueries to achieve what you want:

```
Model::whereIn("name", function ($query) use ($link) {
    $query->select("name")
        ->from((new Model)->getTable())
        ->where("link", $link);
})->get();
```

Comment: If I wanted to do a "leftJoin" on the "with(new Model)" part, how would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$results = Model::whereIn('name', function($query) use ($link) {
    $query->from((new Model)->getTable())
          ->where('link', $link)
          ->select('name');
})->get();
```

**OR** with DB *(update the `table_name` with real one)*

```
$results = DB::select(
    "SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE `name` IN (SELECT `name` FROM `table_name` WHERE `link` = :link)", 
    [ "link" => $link ]
);
```